# Hadoop Running pig script with spesific map reduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

After writing my first Map Reduce in java and written my first pig script .
How do I tell the pig engine which map reduce job to use ?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am just trying to figure out if pig scrip work similar to map reduce. Working on different data node and creating splited files on hdfs, does it ?

Comment: Yes it does. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/test.html#mapreduce-job-ids